# What is the difference between these two Chrome Extension auth APIs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am struggling to figure out the difference between this API call:

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()
```

and this one:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken()
```

what is the difference between them? When I use the getAuthToken(), it will launch an auth flow too in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getAuthToken() is only for Google services.

The documentation states that launchWebAuthFlow() "enables auth flows with non-Google identity providers by launching a web view and navigating it to the first URL in the provider's auth flow."

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity

Comment: thanks I wonder if `getAuthToken()` always uses a Google Chrome Profile?